# Al mandar mensaje solo se refleja en un div del chat y no en dos

Tags: javascript

Creé dos chats en la misma página.

La idea es que al escribir un mensaje y tocar enviar ese mensaje se vea en las dos pantallas (o sea en los dos `<div>`, en el `<div>` del chat 1 y en el `<div>` del chat 2), pero solo se ve en el `div` de uno de ellos, el del otro no se muestra nada.

Están los dos en la misma pantalla por lo que debería funcionar bien, no es algo avanzado lo que estoy haciendo, pero no funciona, ya no sé qué hacer, me estoy volviendo loco.

¿Alguien me sabe decir que esta pasando?

Ésta es mi página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#39ff14">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/50f9a8590c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pantalla">
        <div class="usuario1 ">
            <div class="contacto">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C-Xq00uXYAUUJmE.jpg" alt="img Contacto" class="imgContacto">
                </div>
                <h3 class="nombreContacto">Contacto</h3>
                <button class="ajustes"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogo dialogo1"></div>
            <div class="envio">
                <input type="text" class="mensajeRedactar redacto1" placeHolder="Introduzca un mensaje" spellcheck="false">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="mensajeEnviar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="usuario2 ">
            <div class="contacto">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwMmIswqjw9DvzCAYNHztlSW4WQoCBQYN89X1JN3hfMk101ZLQSm2TvLo_nH4LfMCe5Zs&usqp=CAU" alt="img Contacto" class="imgContacto">
                </div>
                <h3 class="nombreContacto">Contacto</h3>
                <button class="ajustes"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogo dialogo2"></div>
            <div class="envio">
                <input type="text" class="mensajeRedactar redacto2" placeHolder="Introduzca un mensaje" spellcheck="false">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="mensajeEnviar">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


"use strict"

let btnEnvio = document.querySelectorAll(".mensajeEnviar");
let inputU1 = document.querySelector(".redacto1");
let inputU2 = document.querySelector(".redacto2");
let input = [inputU1, inputU2];
let dialogo1 = document.querySelector(".dialogo1");
let dialogo2 = document.querySelector(".dialogo2");
let dialogos = [dialogo1, dialogo2];
let chat;
let mensaje;
let ajustes = document.querySelectorAll(".ajustes");


for (let i = 0; i < btnEnvio.length; i++) {
    btnEnvio[i].addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        chat = document.createElement("DIV");
        chat.classList.add("chat");
        chat.textContent = input[i].value;
        for (let i = 0; i < dialogos.length; i++) {
            dialogos[i].appendChild(chat);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, ahora si que deberia funcionarte

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Un título bien elegido, que describa el problema, hace una pregunta mucho más atractiva

Comment: Bueno, tal como te han recomendado, si quieres seguir pidiendo ayuda debes aprender las normas de este sitio. Mírate [ask] y haz el [tour] para ello.  Tambien, si mi respuesta responde a tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que no quede pendiente para siempre. Para ello aprendelo en este enlace tambien: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428  (lo se, son muchos enlaces y mucho que aprender, pero es por tu bien y el de la comunidad, para que podamos ayudarte mejor)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
for (let i = 0; i < btnEnvio.length; i++) {
    btnEnvio[i].addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        for (let j = 0; j < dialogos.length; j++) {
            chat = document.createElement("DIV");
            chat.classList.add("chat");
            chat.textContent = input[i].value;
            dialogos[j].appendChild(chat);
        }
    });
}
```

Como ves, he cambiado la `i` por una `j` porque si te fijas, la variable `i` ya la estabas usando antes, y además he puesto todo dentro del bucle de los dialogos para poder crear los nodos correctamente, pues segun parece de la otra forma solo funcionaba uno.

Aqui te lo muestro funcionando:

```js
"use strict"

let btnEnvio = document.querySelectorAll(".mensajeEnviar");
let inputU1 = document.querySelector(".redacto1");
let inputU2 = document.querySelector(".redacto2");
let input = [inputU1, inputU2];
let dialogo1 = document.querySelector(".dialogo1");
let dialogo2 = document.querySelector(".dialogo2");
let dialogos = [dialogo1, dialogo2];
let chat;
let mensaje;
let ajustes = document.querySelectorAll(".ajustes");


for (let i = 0; i < btnEnvio.length; i++) {
    btnEnvio[i].addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        for (let j = 0; j < dialogos.length; j++) {
            chat = document.createElement("DIV");
            chat.classList.add("chat");
            chat.textContent = input[i].value;
            dialogos[j].appendChild(chat);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#39ff14">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/50f9a8590c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pantalla">
        <div class="usuario1 ">
            <div class="contacto">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C-Xq00uXYAUUJmE.jpg" alt="img Contacto" class="imgContacto">
                </div>
                <h3 class="nombreContacto">Contacto</h3>
                <button class="ajustes"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogo dialogo1"></div>
            <div class="envio">
                <input type="text" class="mensajeRedactar redacto1" placeHolder="Introduzca un mensaje" spellcheck="false">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="mensajeEnviar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="usuario2 ">
            <div class="contacto">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwMmIswqjw9DvzCAYNHztlSW4WQoCBQYN89X1JN3hfMk101ZLQSm2TvLo_nH4LfMCe5Zs&usqp=CAU" alt="img Contacto" class="imgContacto">
                </div>
                <h3 class="nombreContacto">Contacto</h3>
                <button class="ajustes"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="dialogo dialogo2"></div>
            <div class="envio">
                <input type="text" class="mensajeRedactar redacto2" placeHolder="Introduzca un mensaje" spellcheck="false">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="mensajeEnviar">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```